# Droppable vs Clickable in Jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

We have been using the drag and drop function successfully via jQuery on certain images. Below is the how we have the droppable.

```
$('.t1 span.droppable').each(function(){
      $('.droppable').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    //the drop function is done here.
}
```

Now we are trying for image on click. First we did this it does not work at all.

```
$('.t1 span img.clickable').each(function(){           
          $('.clickable').clickable({
            click: function(event, ui) {
             alert("TYEST");
             };
          });
});
```

Next we tried this it works but if there are 20 images it alerts 20 times.

```
$('.t1 span img.clickable').each(function(){        

    $('.clickable').click(function(){
                       alert("TEST");
           });

});
```

What is the best mechanism to solve this ?

Comment: Well, you're using `.each()` `img` , if you have 20 `img` it will fire for every tag he finds.

Comment: @Steo ok david have solved it by just putting the return false but why its functionality I am not too sure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.t1 span img.clickable').each(function(){        
    $('.clickable').click(function(){
                       alert("TEST");
           });
     return false;

});
```

Add a return false and that should fix it.

Comment: thank you that works so why is the return false is needed what is its functionality?

Comment: the click event is added to each so once its is clicked it propagates up the chain. Return false stops that, it is similar to doing .stopPropagation   http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Ok thank you.Another thing I have this $('.t1 span img.draggable').each(function(){$('.draggable').draggable({helper: 'clone'});}); . In this that what is the role of the helper:'clone' ?